# Tool to monitor MySQL even when a request crashes the server

Tags: mysql, monitoring, server-crashes

It happens quite often that my server goes down (from a few minutes to always).

I think I managed to found the problem, located to mysql that take a big amount of ram to do a request, but since the server is not responding, I can't connect to SSH to analyze it.

Is there a tool that save into a file every actions made by mysql, each request, the size it took to make them, the memory used, cpu, etc.

I'd like to find which request is causing my server to go down about one/two times per week :/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) maybe an option.